# Playwright doesn't store complete local storage

Tags: javascript, automation, local-storage, playwright

`Hi, I'm trying to skip login steps in my test using Playwright Local Storage, but from some reason file that is create contains only few information which I cannot use in order to skip login.
Do you maybe know what is the issue here?

This the code I use

```
test('Positive Login', async ({page}) => {
    const authFile = 'e2e/.auth/userAuth.json'
    
    await loginPage.loginToApp(login_email, login_password);
    await loginPage.clickLoginButton();
    await page.context().storageState({ path: authFile });
  })
```

But userAuth.json file have only those info

```
  "cookies": [],
  "origins": [
    {
      "origin": "https://staging.uxtest.oculid.com",
      "localStorage": [
        {
          "name": "userpilotSettings",
          "value": "{\"endpoint\":\"wss://analytex-eu.userpilot.io/v0/events/websocket\",\"date\":1710280985903}"
        },
        {
          "name": "userpilotSDK",
          "value": "{}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know why stores only this, but not all necessary informations

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass "page" as an argument to loginPage.loginToApp and loginPage.clickLoginButton. if you don't, state of page will not change. That's why userAuth.json file have only origin info.

Example:

```
test('Positive Login', async ({page}) => {
    const authFile = 'e2e/.auth/userAuth.json'
    
    await loginPage.loginToApp(page, login_email, login_password);
    await loginPage.clickLoginButton(page);
    await page.context().storageState({ path: authFile });
  })
```